# Why doesn't this particular regex work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/w8vXG/1/) regex on Javascript :

```
var myString="aaa@aaa.com";
var mailValidator = new RegExp("\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*");
if (!mailValidator.test(myString))
{
    alert("incorrect");
}
```

but it shouldn't alert "incorrect" with `aaa@aaa.com`.

It should return "incorrect" for `aaaaaa.com` instead (as example).

Where am I wrong?

Comment: If you're trying to use a regexp to validate an email address, use [this one instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why this javascript regex doesn't work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427731/why-this-javascript-regex-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you [do this](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/w8vXG/3/):

```
var mailValidator = /\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/;
```

What happens in yours is that you need to double escape the backslash because they're inside a string, like `"\\w+([-+.]\\w+)*...etc`

[Here's a link that explains it](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) (in the "How to Use The JavaScript RegExp Object" section).

Answer (score 2):

When you create a regex from a string, you have to take into account the fact that the parser will strip out backslashes from the string *before* it has a chance to be parsed as a regex.

Thus, by the time the `RegExp()` constructor gets to work, all the `\w` tokens have already been changed to just plain "w" in the string constant.  You can either double the backslashes so the string parse will leave just one, or you can use the native regex constant syntax instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try `var mailValidator = new RegExp("\\w+([-+.]\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*");`