# Finding text before and after a match - jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to do a search and return the snippet that contains the search term.

**Input**: `I am a pilot. I can also play piano, however he am not a

good singer.

I cook Italian.`

**Search**: piano

**Result**: also play piano, however I am not

**Rule**:

- two words before the search term + search term + four words after search term.
- Case insensitive.
- Exact match and if search term is part of a word, it should ignore. Searching for **man** should ignore **Cayman Island**.

  ```
  var needle = "Piano";
  var haystack = "I am a pilot. I can also play piano, however I am not a 

  good singer.
  I cook Italian."; // the user input from a textarea would fill in this variable and would contain new line character

  search_regexp = new RegExp('/([^'+ needle +']+)'+ needle +'([^'+ needle +']+)/', "gi");
  thismatcharray = haystack.match(search_regexp);
  alert(thismatcharray);
  ```

I am keen to understand how can I get an array with the values before and after the search value so that I can concatenate to get the final result. Thanks....

Comment: `[^needle]` = `[^nedl]`. It does not match any char but `needle`, just any char other than the chars inside the character class.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You're more familiar with the js flavor of regex. Any idea why my solution wouldn't work? I'm assuming it's less of a pattern problem and more of a syntax problem.

Comment: @emsimpson92 You are making a very common mistake when passing a variable to the regex. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427731/why-this-javascript-regex-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex. It looks for 1 to 2 groups of a word (`[A-Za-z]+`) followed by optional punctuation (I've allowed for `.` and `,`, you could expand that group as required) and some whitespace, followed by the needle, followed by 1 to 4 groups of optional punctuation, some whitespace and a word. Since the quantifiers are greedy, if there are two words before and four after, that is what they will return.

```js
var needle = "Piano";
var haystack = "I am a pilot. I can also play\n\
\
piano, however I\n\
am not a\n\
good singer.";
search_regexp = new RegExp('((([A-Za-z]+[.,]?\\s+){1,2})('+needle+')(([.,]?\\s+[A-Za-z]+){1,4}))', "gi");
var thismatcharray = haystack.match(search_regexp);
console.log(thismatcharray);
replace_regexp = new RegExp('^[\\s\\S]*?((([A-Za-z]+[.,]?\\s+){0,2})(\\b'+needle+'\\b)(([.,]?\\s+[A-Za-z]+){0,4}))[\\s\\S]*$', "i");
var output = haystack.replace(replace_regexp, '$2<label style="color: red">$4</label>$5');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: This actually works! One question though if I may? Is there a way to replace the needle with something else? I need to highlight the needle in the search and so typically I would like to replace piano by '<label style="color: red">'+needle+'</label>'

Comment: Did you still want the 2 words before and the 4 after as well as the highlighting?

Comment: yes indeed. that is exactly what would help me with... the results would be >> also play <label style="color: red">piano</label>, however I am not

Comment: A new line character is failing the result.

Comment: Edited the question with an input having new line character

Comment: I don't think that input actually has a newline character in it, if it did it would match the `\s` in the regex. My edited answer has actual newlines and works fine.

Comment: I think I found what is causing it to fail. As you can observe in the question, If I have two new lines it is failing. Just one works well.

Comment: I suppose I can insert a line haystack = $.trim(haystack.replace(/[\t\n]+/g,' ')) before match statement to solve such issues....

Comment: Also note that instead of {1,2}, {1,4} I used {0,2} and {0,4} respectively.

Comment: I reckon there is problem, If the input is changed to pianozz, it is failing.. Is there a way for exact word match. It should should fail if the needle forms part of other words. I am thinking if the name capianola is in the input, it would pick that as well!

Comment: fixed by amending to replace_regexp = new RegExp('^.*?((([A-Za-z]+[.,]?\\s+){0,2})(\\b'+needle+'\\b)(([.,]?\\s+[A-Za-z]+){0,4})).*$', "i");

Comment: Glad you got it sorted - sorry couldn't offer more, I was sleeping... I'll edit the post to bring it up to date with the regex that worked.

Comment: You may also want to add $.trim(haystack.replace(/[\t\n]+/g,' ')) before .match statement to make it foolproof. You have been really helpful

Comment: Actually see my latest edit, the problem was that `.` won't match newline in JS, so need to change `.*` to `[\\s\\S]*` at beginning and end of `replace_regexp`, then it's not necessary to trim