# taking out html from a string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Hi,

I have a string that looks like this:

```
<span class='$variable'>
```

I want to strip everything else but the $variable inside so I tried this:

```
string.replace('/<span class=\'/','/\'>/');
```

I have used this regex on php but it doesnt seem to work on javascript. What is the correct regex in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: It's regex basic... Try something relevant first (take 10 minutes regex tour).

Comment: yeah well, as I said, this one works on php but not on javascript so that is of NO HELP at all...

Comment: First JS regex is delimited by `/` without quotes. There you can start.

Comment: It is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427731/why-this-javascript-regex-doesnt-work. Plus you need an alternation here, and global flag, `.replace(/<span class='|'>/g, '')`. Or, `.replace(/<span\s+class='([^']*)'>/, '$1')`

Comment: excellent solution, thanks. I would appreciate it even more if you explain it to me because im lost at regex. Is `|` the character you always use to indicate the wildcard character which should not be replaced?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```js
.replace(/<span class='(.*?)'>/, '$1')
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/BYbm6f/1).

**EXPLANATION**

| PATTERN | MEANING |
| --- | --- |
| `<span class='` | `<span class='` |
| `(` | group and capture to `$1`: |
| `.*?` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the least amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of `$1` |
| `'>` | `'>` |

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation. What is the meaning of the 2 `/`?

Comment: @CainNuke Regex delimiters. Make up a regex literal. See "The literal notation" at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#description