# global Regexp is returning incorrect index inside for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to remove a timestamp (formatted as numbers dash numbers) from a string. In the process I experimented with global RegExp. I came up with the following code:

```
for(let filename of ["123-123_aaa_bbb_ccc","aaa_bbb_ccc_129-999"])
{
  let s=filename.split("_")
  let globalRegex = new RegExp('^\d+\-\d+$', 'g');
  for(let si of s){
    if(globalRegex.test(si)) break
  }
  console.log(`match found at: `,globalRegex.lastIndex)
}
```

which returns:

```
match found at:  0
match found at:  0
```

My questions are:

1. How do I correctly remove the timestamp from the string?
2. Why is the regexp returning 0 for both runs?

- I expected (0 then 3 index to be returned) It seems like the state
  of the global regex isnt being reinitialized for the second run.
  However I assumed it would be, since it is redeclared inside the for
  loop

Comment: You have to double escape the backslash in the RegExp constructor, but then the pattern `^\d+\-\d+$` does not match any of the strings. The "timestamp" part is `123-123` and `129-999` ?

Comment: Don't use `new RegExp` if you're not creating the regexp dynamically. Just use a RegExp literal. Also, don't use the `g` flag if you're using the regexp for testing rather than iterating over all the matches.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results regarding the `g` flag.

Comment: To replace the "timestamps" `["123-123_aaa_bbb_ccc","aaa_bbb_ccc_129-999"].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(/\d+-\d+/, "")));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few issues here:

- You get `0`s because your regex does not match, and it does not match because you defined the regex string inside a regular string literal, thus, losing all single backslashes. The pattern must be set with a regex literal, `let globalRegex = /^\d+\-\d+$/;` (see [Why this javascript regex doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7427731/3832970)). Note the absence of the `g` flag, if you use it with `RegExp#test()`, you must not use `g` flag to avoid issues (see [Why does a RegExp with global flag give wrong results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1520800/3832970)).
- Even if you define the regex properly you will get `0`s as output because a `/^\d+\-\d+$/` regex can and will only match at the start of the string (Index=0). You seeem to want to get the IDs of the "words" or "tokens" in the string, so you need to count them.

So, you could re-write the code as

```js
for(let filename of ["123-123_aaa_bbb_ccc","aaa_bbb_ccc_129-999"])
{
  let result = -1;
  let s=filename.split("_")
  let globalRegex = /^\d+\-\d+$/;
  for (const [index, si] of s.entries()) {
    if(globalRegex.test(si)) {
        result = index
        break
    }
  }
  console.log(`match found at: `, result)
}
```